# problems with images in Shoes GUI toolkit on Windows

Tags: ruby, image, user-interface, shoes

I have some problems with images in shoes (green shoes, ruby 2.1):

- when I apply height and width I get this error:

  'image': undefined method `scale' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
- when I remove the height and width params the app runs but there is no image, just the blank icon

I use .png format.

These problems happened when I moved from Linux to Windows and I realized they're probably related to ImageMagick and rmagick.

Even after ImageMagick installation it didn't work. So I've tried installing rmagick as well and the installation of rmagick failed:

ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

If the image problem is related to the ImageMagick how can I solve this?

I wanted to share my app with others and that's a problem if they don't have these dependencies. Is there any other solution of image format that works with Shoes? 
I've tried .jpg and -jpeg and the result is the same.

Thank you.

Regards

seba

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't in the shoes or ruby. I found out that it was in running the script directly from Komodo.

From the command line works fine (w/o imagemagick).

regards,

seba